# How to turn a function output, into a number

Tags: bash, function, if-statement, floating-point, sh

So want to turn this function, whose output is a number. The number is curled through some json file thats irrelevant.

```
#error input 1
if (($(masterfunc) >= 1)); then
#I've also tried
#error input 2
if (($(masterfunc | bc -l) >= 1)); then
```

I get these this error, which I'm assuming is because its outputing it as a letter or command and not as a number.

```
#error output 1
((: 1.00048333447157914468 >= 1: syntax error: invalid arithmetic 
operator (error token is ".00048333447157914468 >= 1")
#error output 2
((: .99989817794934530799 >= 1: syntax error: operand expected (error 
token is ".99989817794934530799 >= 1")
```

I'm assuming this is some floating point arithmetic problem, but then it should of been solved through bc?

I'm new to bash so if the problem is some unrelated syntax error I apologize.

Comment: `((...))` simply doesn't support floating point. You can't use `bc` *inside* the parentheses as that still leaves `((...))` with floating point numbers.  You need to do all of the math with `bc` and ditch `((...))`.

Comment: Look up, i did use bc.

Comment: I've looked at the floating point division in bash, no relevant info that i didn't know.

Comment: @CaucasianMalaysian You used `bc`, but not in a relevant way. When you just pipe the number to `bc`, it looks at it, says "yep, that's a number" to itself, and then prints it *still as a real number*. Bash then tries to compare that with 1, but it's still a real number, so it fails. You need to have `bc` do the actual comparison, so all bash needs to deal with is a simple yes/no (or 1/0).

Comment: So bc does the -ge part, what do you put in substitution for asking the if function to do a simple yes/no? Do you make it repeat the same comparison you're pipelining into bc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually rather complicated. The shell doesn't understand real numbers at all, so you have to get something else (like `bc`) to do the comparison and output something simpler that bash can understand. The simplest way I see to do this is:

```
if [ $(echo "$(masterfunc) >= 1" | bc) -eq 1 ]; then
```

Explanation, step by step:

- `echo "$(masterfunc) >= 1"` runs the `masterfunc` function, adds ">= 1" to its output, and sends the result (something like "1.00048333447157914468 >= 1") to standard output.
- `echo "$(masterfunc) >= 1" | bc` runs the above and pipes it to `bc`, which will do the comparison and print "1" if the `masterfunc` output is greater than or equal to 1, "0" if it's less. Note: you can try running this by hand and see how it works.

  This "1"/"0" output is more along the lines of what bash can understand, but we still need to actually tell bash what to make of it.
- `[ $(echo "$(masterfunc) >= 1" | bc) -eq 1 ]` runs the above, captures its output with `$( )`, and embeds that in a test expression. Basically, depending on the output from `bc`, this is equivalent to either `[ 1 -eq 1 ]` or `[ 0 -eq 1 ]`.

Comment: There you go. I was going to use `$?` resulting from `echo "$(masterfunc) >= 1" | bc`, but throwing it all in `test` works too.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
if (( $(printf '%s >= 1\n' "$(masterfunc)" | bc -l) )); then ...
```